# Identify GCP HTTP(s) Cloud Function Invoker's identity inside Python code

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Is there a simple way to get the Invoker's username/email when a cloud function has been called using: `gcloud functions call <function-name>`

The cloud function is supposed to generate something for the user, but needs to use the username.

Passing it using `--data` parameter is not suitable as that way, we can't verify if the user is passing their own username or something else.

I've printed the headers inside the function, but they don't contain anything to do with the User who called it.

Comment: The `gcloud functions call` is for testing purpose. What is your use case? Why do you need the user on this type of invocation?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It doesn't matter if its gcloud functions call or a curl with token, when you get to the CF code, the end result is the same. In any case, I managed to get user's details in the function. Will post it as answer to my question. My use case was specified in my question. In short, the CF creates a resource in GCP that will contain user's username and needed a way to verify who the user is without allowing users to just pass their own username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up passing an id_token in the payload to the CF and inside it using a google python library to validate it and extract the user email.

Although not the same use case, I found some sample code here: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/idtoken-auth

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)
# ...

try:
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
    user_email = idinfo['email']
    #From here on I can split the email and get the username...
    #Now that I have the username, I can create the resources I needed with their username appended to the resource name.
except ValueError:
    # Invalid token
    pass
```

The token was passed to the CF in the payload data like this: `{"identity_token":"$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"}` from user side.

Hopefully this comes in handy for someone that has similar use case.